# SQLSTATE[HY000] General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 14) (SQL: select * from [produto])

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel-5.5

Tenho uma aplicação em laravel conectando no banco em um SQL Server quando vou fazer uma consulta de todos os produtos estou recebendo o erro

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 14) (SQL: select * from [produto])
```

**database.php**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MpiWeb'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxxxx'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

**Woocontroller.php**

```
public function mpiweb(){ 
$listaprodutos = Everest::all();
    return $listaprodutos;
}
```

Comment: @MarceloRafael acredito que a query seja a que está na pergunta: `select * from [produto]`

Comment: As suas credencias funcionam corretamente se você usar fora da aplicação? Pelo que vi severity 14 é causado por problemas de login.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440063/3956218